# Spark standalone mode on local file system

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

Why does Spark java driver program forces me to install winutils.exe, that are considered as Hadoop binary, if I want to run it in standalone mode on local non-HDFS file system?

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testFile="test.iml";
        SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("Test application").setMaster("local[*]");

        JavaSparkContext sparkContext=new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> logData=sparkContext.textFile(testFile).cache();

        long numAs=logData.filter((s)->s.contains("a")).count();
        long numBs= logData.filter((s)->s.contains("b")).count();

        System.out.println(numBs);
        System.out.println(numAs);

    }
}
```

Error message

```
ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```